# Set Proxy-Authorization Header in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, http-headers

I'm shocked I couldn't really find anything online about this, but I'm running into trouble when I try to send a proxy authorization in the header of my ajax call. If I send is as below, I don't get an error, but the server doesn't see the proxy authorization in the header:

```
$.ajax({
     url:"https://myurl.com",
     beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Proxy-Authorization', 'Basic XXX');}
});
```

If I send the call as follows below, I get an error that says: **Refused to set unsafe header "Proxy-Authorization"**

```
$.ajax({
     url:"https://myurl.com",
     headers:{
         "Authorization":_this.pasToken,
         "Proxy-Authorization":'Basic xxx'
     }    
});
```

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, and I'm going to post the answer just in case it helps anyone else.

According to [this](http://news.anarchy46.net/2012/06/refused-to-set-unsafe-header.html), **Chrome won't let you set the Proxy-Authorization header**.